# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value' - Python API for Azure DevOps

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, devops

I am trying to use Python API from https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api
but getting error like:

> "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'value'"

[image: thon]

Below is the snippet

```
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
import pprint

# Fill in with your personal access token and org URL
personal_access_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
organization_url = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', personal_access_token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

# Get a client (the "core" client provides access to projects, teams, etc)
core_client = connection.clients.get_core_client()

# Get the first page of projects
get_projects_response = core_client.get_projects()
index = 0
while get_projects_response is not None:
    for project in get_projects_response.value:
        pprint.pprint("[" + str(index) + "] " + project.name)
        index += 1
    if get_projects_response.continuation_token is not None and get_projects_response.continuation_token != "":
        # Get the next page of projects
        get_projects_response = core_client.get_projects(continuation_token=get_projects_response.continuation_token)
    else:
        # All projects have been retrieved
        get_projects_response = None
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error means that either you do not have projects active for the credentials you've provided or the object `get_projects_response` does not have an attribute value

You can try and print this before the loop and you will be able to see that you would likely be getting an empty dictionary.

```
print(get_projects_response)#update the output of this to your question to get a better clarity
```

Comment: If list is empty, it would not throw that error. It would just go through and will not go inside for loop. The problem is that object `get_projects_response` does not have an attribute `value`, and this is a reason for exception. You can remove `.value` and it should run OK.

Answer (score 0):

Actually response to <get_projects_response> is saved as list, so to print the list try replacing,

```
while get_projects_response is not None:
for project in get_projects_response.value:
    pprint.pprint("[" + str(index) + "] " + project.name)
    index += 1
if get_projects_response.continuation_token is not None and get_projects_response.continuation_token != "":
    # Get the next page of projects
    get_projects_response = core_client.get_projects(continuation_token=get_projects_response.continuation_token)
else:
    # All projects have been retrieved
    get_projects_response = None
```

to

```
for project in get_projects_response:
   pprint.pprint("[" + str(index) + "] " + project.name)
   index += 1
```